# calling locals() in a function nested in a class method

Tags: python

Here is a snippet:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self, x):
        def baz(y):
            print locals()['self']
        ..
        return baz(..)

foo = Foo()
foo.bar(..)
```

I have 2 boxes. On Windows Vista with Python 2.5 calling `foo.bar(..)` works. On Ubuntu with Python 2.7 calling `foo.bar(..)` throws a `KeyError`, not being able to find `self` in locals() dict.

Any ideas?

**Edit: I owe an apology; it seems I have misguided you while trying to frame the problem.** The actual code in the nested function evaluates a string coming from a DSL:

```
            r = re.compile(r'\$(\w+)')
            eval_string = r.sub(r'self.player.stats["\1"]', s)
            result = eval(eval_string)
```

It runs Vista/Python 2.5, fails on Ubuntu/Python 2.7.

Comment: It this just out of curiosity, or is part of solving a real problem? If it is part of a real problem, we might be able to sugest a better way to do it, since it's rare for you to need to use `locals()`.

Comment: This snippet is not correct. Calling foo.bar() actually does nothing as there is nothing returned and you are not calling baz

Comment: @Jeremy: The code is just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I'm confused now. Can we see a complete, coherent example?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: Unit tests for the same code fails on Linux, passes on Windows. I'm currently delving into the issue. I'll provide a complete example, even maybe the solution as soon as I can.

Comment: @shanyu Why the hell writing ``baz(..)`` and ``foo.bar(..)`` with two dots ????

Comment: @eyquem `(..)` is meant to be a place-holder for omitted parameters to the function (OP figures they are not important to the question).

Comment: in that context wouldn't you easily be able to do `result = self.player.stats[MATCH]` where `MATCH` is the matching group gotten from `r.match(s).group(1)` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Admitting that you can compute the variables dict before running bad, you can use this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self, x):
        outer_locals = locals()
        def baz(y):
            print outer_locals['self']
        ..
        return baz(..)
```

If, instead, you have to compute the dictionary at runtime (inside `bad`), this is the way to go:

```
import inspect

def outer_locals(depth=0):
    """
    With depth=0 behaves like locals(), depth=1 are the locals of the
    containing frame, depth=2 the locals of the frame containing the containing
    frame and so on...
    """
    return inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[depth+1][0].f_locals

class Foo(object):
    def bar(self, x):
        def baz(y):
            print outer_locals(1)
        return baz(...)
```

Note that if not overwritten in the `baz` function, all of `bar` locals are available in `bad`:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self, x):
        def baz(y):
            print self
        ..
        return baz(..)
```

Comment: The problem is that my snippet works in one configuration and not in the other.

Comment: @shanyu: (I added a new example) Which configurations are you talking about? I tested both of the presented ones and they work. Maybe you have to provide more context of your snippets.

Comment: Configurations: Vista/Python2.5, Ubuntu/Python2.7. My snippet shouldn't work on the latter configuration, are you sure it works?

Comment: Pretty sure yes, if that is the only code you have. As I said, you may have to provide more context: http://pastebin.com/FnLjdieu

Comment: Mmmmh... looking at it, it works as I implemented it, but `self` is not in the `baz` locals dict, so `locals()['self']` is NOT supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same behavior you report in 2.7 using 2.6.6. However, I *also* get it using 2.5.2 and 2.4.6. (All Linux.)

Interestingly:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
    def bar(self, x):
        def baz(y):
            print self.__class__.__name__
            print locals()['self']
        return baz(4)
...
>>> Foo().bar(3)
Foo
<__main__.Foo object at 0x9801f4c>
>>>
```

Presumably there was some optimization or alteration of the process of computing the local symbol table whereby only names actually used in a given function's scope are added to its table, even if a given symbol *would* be accessible (and would not be a global!) *were* it to be explicitly referred to.

Changing the last line of bar() to `return baz` (rather than `return baz(4)`) we can see that `self` is not a local variable; it's a free variable:

```
>>> baz = Foo().bar(4)
>>> baz.func_code.co_nlocals, f.func_code.co_varnames, f.func_code.co_freevars
(1, ('y',), ('self',))
```

Even here, though, `x` has not been included among the free variables, because [when the name isn't used in the interior function, it doesn't count as free there](http://bugs.python.org/issue6925#msg92809).

That explanation, though, makes the behavior you're describing under 2.5 on Vista sound like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I believe the `KeyError` is correct; I get the same on Python 2.7.1 on OSX SnowLeopard.

Here's why.  I modified your code to the following:

```
class Foo(object):

    def bar(self, x):
        quux = 4
        print locals()

        def baz(y):
            print locals()#['self']

        return baz(3)

foo = Foo()
foo.bar(2)
```

and got

```
{'quux': 4, 'self': <__main__.Foo object at 0x1004945d0>, 'x': 2}
{'y': 3}
```

The issue is that in `baz` the `locals` dict should *not* include `self` which is defined in an outer scope.

I'm really puzzled why this found `self` in `baz`'s locatls under Windows.  Either it is a bug in 2.5 or in the Windows implementation, or the language spec has changed between 2.5 and 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

The local variables are **always** the ones defined within the current called function, the global variables are **always** the ones defined at the top of your program.
In `bar` *self* is a local variable. In `baz` *self* is somewhere inbetween the local and global variables. You can still reference it because Python will search for it in higher scopes as it's not defined in the local one, but
you cannot access theese scopes' dictionary.