# Why can't eval find a variable defined in an outer function?

Tags: python, eval, local-variables

I am aware that the use of `eval()` usually means bad code, but I stumbled upon a weird behavior of the `eval()` function in internal functions that I could not understand. If we write:

```
def f(a):
    def g():
        print(eval('a'))
    return g()
```

Running `f(1)` in this case yields a `NameError`, claiming that `a` is not defined. However, if we define

```
def f(a):
    def g():
        b = a + 1
        print(eval('a'))
    return g()
```

Then running `f(1)` prints `1`.

There is something happening with local and global variables that I can't quite understand. Is `a` only a local variable in `g()` when it is "used" for something? What is going on here?

Comment: have a look in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881282/calling-locals-in-a-function-nested-in-a-class-method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, since `eval` is for dynamic evaluation, the interpreter has no way to know it should add `a` to the local scope of `g`. For efficiency, the interpreter will not add unneeded variables to the `dict` of local variables.

From the doc for [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#eval):

> The expression argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression (technically speaking, a condition list) using the globals and locals dictionaries as global and local namespace.

This means the functions `eval(expression)` will use `globals()` as its default global scope and `locals()` as its local scope if none are provided.

Although, in you first example `a` is in neither.

```
def f(a):
    print("f's locals:", locals())
    def g():
        print("g's locals:", locals())
        print(eval('a'))
    return g()

f(1)
```

Indeed, since the interpreter sees no reference to `a` when parsing the body of `g`, it does not add it to its local variables.

For it to work, you would need to specify `nonlocal a` in `g`.

### Output

```
f's locals: {'a': 1}
g's locals: {}
Traceback ...
...
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

In your second example, `a` is in `g` local variables as it is used in the scope.

```
def f(a):
    print("f's locals:", locals())
    def g():
        print("g's locals:", locals())
        b = a + 1
        print("g's locals after b = a + 1:", locals())
        print(eval('a'))
    return g()

f(1)
```

### Output

```
f's locals: {'a': 1}
g's locals: {'a': 1}
g's locals after b = a + 1: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
1
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like eval() can only look for variables in local(here,g) or global, but not its parent environment (here f). A walk around is to set the variable as global.

```
 
def f(a):    
    global b #note, can not use "global a" directly,  will get error:"name 'a' is parameter and global"
    b=a
    def g():
        print(eval('b'))
    return g()
f(1)
```

output: 1